# Device Orientation and compass

Tags: javascript, html, device-orientation

Do I need a compass in the device to detect orientation.
The [demo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation) on MDN gives me null as the value of orientation. And yes I don't a compass on the mobile device I'm testing with.

Comment: Device orientation should be done by means of a gyroscope, which are built-in

Comment: you mean like emulate it via acceleration